# Terraform 12 convert count to for_each

Tags: list, github, set, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am currently experiencing some challenges with the way that count index's in Terraform. I am seeking some help to convert this to for_each.

```
# Data Source for github repositories. This is used for adding all repos to the teams.
data "github_repositories" "repositories" {
  query = "org:theorg"
}

resource "github_team_repository" "business_analysts" {
  count      = length(data.github_repositories.repositories.names)
  team_id    = github_team.Business_Analysts.id
  repository = element(data.github_repositories.repositories.names, count.index)
  permission = "pull"
}
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
resource "github_team_repository" "business_analysts" { 

for_each = toset(data.github_repositories.repositories.names) 
team_id = github_team.Business_Analysts.id 
repository = "${each.value}" 
permission = "pull" 
}
```

I am querying a Github organization and receiving a huge list of repositories. I am then using count to add those repositories to a Team. Unfortunately, Terraform will error out once a new repository is added or changed. This being said I think the new for_each function could solve this dilemma for me however, I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement it; in this particular scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried with for_each? Did you get an error with something you tried? If so could you show what you tried and the relevant error?

Comment: resource "github_team_repository" "business_analysts" {
  for_each   = toset(data.github_repositories.repositories.names)
  team_id    = github_team.Business_Analysts.id
  repository = "${each.value}"
  permission = "pull"
}

Comment: You should edit that into your question along with any errors you got.

Comment: When you say "with no success" do you get an error? If so can you edit your question to include the error please? If it doesn't error but doesn't do what you're expecting could you explain what it did do? This explanation should also be in the question itself rather than a comment.

Comment: We really need to see the error, or actual output versus expected. However, using my crystal ball, I think you may need to change `each.value` to `each.key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False Alarm. The I had the answer all along and the issue was attributed to the way I was referencing a variable.....

if someone stumbles upon this then you want to structure your loop like so

```
for_each = toset(data.github_repositories.repositories.names) 
team_id = github_team.Business_Analysts.id 
repository = each.key 
permission = "pull" 
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. **each.key** and **each.value** are equal in the case of **for_each** on a set. What error did you get with the original implementation?